# How can I play another mp3 file without having to close the current playing file in vlc?

Tags: 12.04, command-line, sound, vlc

I played a song via terminal. I tried the following and it gave me this result:-

```
siddhartharao17@siddhartharao-PC:/media/LENOVO/Music/Hindi Asorted/Ek villain$ vlc --audio Galliyan.mp3 
VLC media player 2.0.8 Twoflower (revision 2.0.8a-0-g68cf50b)
[0x814b908] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.

(vlc:4731): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "equinox",

(vlc:4731): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "equinox",

(vlc:4731): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(vlc:4731): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "equinox",

(vlc:4731): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(vlc:4731): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "equinox",

(vlc:4731): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "equinox",

(vlc:4731): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "equinox",

(vlc:4731): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "equinox",

(vlc:4731): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(vlc:4731): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(vlc:4731): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "equinox",

(vlc:4731): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "equinox",

(vlc:4731): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "equinox",

(vlc:4731): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "equinox",

(vlc:4731): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "equinox",

(vlc:4731): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(vlc:4731): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(vlc:4731): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(vlc:4731): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(vlc:4731): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(vlc:4731): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "equinox",

(vlc:4731): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "equinox",

(vlc:4731): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "equinox",

(vlc:4731): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "equinox",

(vlc:4731): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(vlc:4731): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(vlc:4731): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(vlc:4731): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(vlc:4731): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
```

now, the query I have is, if I want to change the song from the same terminal(without opening a new one), how to do it?
I have been searching,googling, also tried reading the "vlc --help", but it din't help me.
I believe I'll get my answer here.
Than you in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear what you want exactly, to play music from the command line, without an interface?

In that event, use cvlc as indicated in the output

> Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.

So

```
cvlc --your-options --audio Galliyan.mp3
```

You should be able to repeat the command after the mp3 is done playing.

Or are you wanting to play 2 tracks at the same time ? with vlc ? Some players do not allow you to open multiple instances at the same time (I am not sure about vlc). If you can not do this with vlc, either use a different player which allows multiple instances, either graphical or command line, or use 2 different players. I know you can play music at the same time from firefox, audacity, and audacious, but I am not sure this is what you want either.

An alternate command line mp3 player ? there are several, aplay is a simple one. There are many very nice alternates, see http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/rock-out-your-console-out

Or are you wanting to continue to use the terminal? In this event use an "&"

```
cvlc --your-options --audio Galliyan.mp3 &
```

You can redirect error messages and close the terminal

```
nohup cvlc --your-options --audio Galliyan.mp3 &> /dev/null &
```

Comment: Thank you for such a descriptive explaination, Sir :)
It worked!!
But could you please tell what is the significance of '&' in the end??

Comment: The & at the end puts the command in the background and you can continue to use the terminal to run additional commands.

Answer (score 1):

You should set your VLC preferences to allow multiple instances to run. To open VLC preferences, open VLC and go to **Tools -> Preferences** and confirm that there is no check mark over "Use only one instance when started from file manager" and over ""Allow only one instance".

[image: Screenshot vlc preferences]

Now, start your file from the terminal as follows:

```
vlc --audio filename &
```

Note the `&` at the end of the command. Now you don't have to terminate your currently running file to start a new one.

Comment: @Siddhartha: Please mark the answer as accepted(click on the tick mark besides the answer) since it has helped you.